# The two same strings are not equal to each other. Why?

Tags: java, android

I'm working on an android mobile application by using Firebase.

I can get the data which name is "EgeUniversity" but when I compare it with:

```
String name = "EgeUniversity";
```

They not equal each other.

This is my code to get the user's university name:

```
FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase3 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance ();
    DatabaseReference myRefNe2= firebaseDatabase3.getReference ("users");

    myRefNe2.addValueEventListener ( new ValueEventListener ( ) {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            FirebaseAuth mAuth37 =FirebaseAuth.getInstance ();

            String userNameCurrent = mAuth37.getCurrentUser ().getDisplayName ();

            universityofUser24 = dataSnapshot.child ( userNameCurrent ).child ( "universityName" ).getValue (String.class);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            Toast.makeText ( getApplicationContext (),databaseError.getMessage (),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show ();
        }
    } );
```

And I used the following code to get another data from firebase by using "university name".

```
 DatabaseReference newReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference ( "Posts/"+universityofUser24 );
    newReference.addValueEventListener ( new ValueEventListener ( ) {...
```

But the values are not equal to each other. 
 I mean;

```
String nameofUni = "EgeUniversity";
```

nameofUni is not equal to universityofUser24.

But when I write them by using "Log.d" they seem exactly same.

I have controlled the empty-spaces by using "trim()" by the way.

[image: DataBase Structure]

Comment: Yep, a typo. Double-checking your spelling helps!

Comment: Show us the "Log.d", then maybe we can see the difference you can't.

Comment: Can you post the code you're using to compare the strings?

Comment: .sametdeneme1 D/OUTPUT: the data comes from data base is: EgeUniversity
.sametdeneme1 D/OUTPUT: the data: EgeUniversity

Comment: When I change the name of path to this form "Users/EgeUniversity" it works.

Comment: Sammy T, actullay I don't compare these strings in my code. But they have to be same to get the data from database. First I get the user's university name to put the right place the data. For example my university name Dokuz Eylül then the code puts my data to Dokuz Eylül.

Comment: When two strings which print the same are not equal, they may contain non-printing characters. Firstly, try comparing their lengths: differing lengths are obviously not equal. If lengths are equal, try looking at the char arrays, and see if the elements are what you expect.

Comment: I'm not sure what your final screenshot is meant to show, but is the space in "Ege University" Vs the lack of space in "EgeUniversity" significant?

Comment: Andy T, I have already controlled the length of strings and they exactly have the same length. Tomorrow, I will check the charArray. What happens if the exactly same two string are not equal to each other? I mean, how can we fix this problem? They are same before the update process. However, after the update, when I get it from the database it changes.

Answer (score 0):

You said:

I compare it with:

`String name = "EgeUniversity";`

That is not a comparison, that is assignment.

To compare Strings in Java for equality you must use String.equals()

Comment: Thanks for your answer Patrick, but this is not the point which I struggle to explain. I mean, the data that in string form changes when I get it from the database. Same length, same letters but they are not equal/same ...etc.

Comment: Too bad you didn't show where in your code you are testing that they are equal. Because my guess is you are using str1 == str2 instead of str1.equals(str2). It is the most common Java mistake on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

trim() function will remove spaces at the end of the string or at the beginning only!
If you want to delete spaces in the middle of the string you will use another function like:

```
str = str.replaceAll(" ", "");
```

To compare Strings you will use the function equals() and not == :

```
boolean isSame = str1.equals(str2);
```